# Trouble with ObservableCollection and Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, observablecollection

Ok i have a Class Mod defined as

```
public class Mod
{
    public Mod()
    {
        Data = new ObservableCollection<object>();
    }
    public Mod(Mod other)
    {
        Data = new ObservableCollection<object>(other.Data);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<object> Data { get; private set; }
}
```

and a control

```
    <TreeView x:Name="ItemList" DockPanel.Dock="Left" DataContext="{Binding Mod, Source={StaticResource Core}}" >
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="TVTemplate" >
                <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Name}" Tag="{Binding }" ToolTip="{Binding Desc}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item1" ItemsSource="{Binding Data, ConverterParameter={x:Type local:Item1Type}, Converter={StaticResource OMTypeConverter}}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource TVTemplate}"/>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item2" ItemsSource="{Binding Data, ConverterParameter={x:Type local:Item2Type}, Converter={StaticResource OMTypeConverter}}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource TVTemplate}"/>
```

the type converter is defined as

```
public class OMTypeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        List<object> rtn = new List<object>();
        ObservableCollection<object> data= value as ObservableCollection<object>;
        if (data!= null)
        {
            Type type = parameter as Type;
            if (type != null)
            {
                var tmp = data.Where(o => type.IsInstanceOfType(o));
                rtn.AddRange(tmp);

            }
        }
        return rtn;
    }
}
```

when loading the window it works perfectly the type converter shows a value that is an empty Observable collection of objects, however when i then add an item to the OC nothing happened, the converter is not called and the items list appears unchanged on screen

i've confirmed from the code behind that the value has been added to the data collection

so why is the binding not being triggered to update the treeveiwitem?

Comment: Because you're returning a new List everytime and breaking the binding.  Set the ItemsSource of the TreeView to Data instead and set your DataContext. This is ugly code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your converter you are breaking the link with the original collection.

I can think of some workaround but there is a clean solution.

You should use two **collections views** on your Data.

Declare them in your code behind:

```
public ICollectionView Item1TypeView { get; set; }
public ICollectionView Item2TypeView { get; set; }
```

And initialize them in the constructor of your view:

```
Item1TypeView = new CollectionViewSource { Source = Data }.View;
Item1TypeView.Filter = e => e is Item1Type;
Item2TypeView = new CollectionViewSource { Source = Data }.View;
Item2TypeView.Filter = e => e is Item2Type;
```

Then bind each `TreeView` to one of them:

```
<TreeViewItem Header="Item1" ItemsSource="{Binding Item1TypeView}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource TVTemplate}"/>
<TreeViewItem Header="Item2" ItemsSource="{Binding Item2TypeView}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource TVTemplate}"/>
```

No need for converter anymore.

Comment: its actually many more than 2, currently its 18, and could increase. but your suggestion seems workable. i was under the impression that the value converter was applied after the binding so couldn't affect the event binding on CollectionChanged

Comment: Yes you can generate them dynamically in a loop if you don't want to have too much code duplication.

Comment: You're right.  A clean solution would be something like a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` or a template selector, or something of the similar; NOT a converter.

Comment: I considered that but couldn't figure out how to group by the objects type and then map the grouping to the tree structure via a hierarchical data template.